# Showing pixel number on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html

I'm starting my own website, and I'm working on a privilege in the site, I'm looking for some code that helps me to do this:

"When I pass the mouse pointer on an image or a background in the site, a cursor appears showing the position of each pixel the mouser passes over, for example (23,234)."

Thanks  in advance

PS : I'm familiar with PHP, HTML, JavaScript

Comment: Removed PHP tag. This is handled entirely on the client side with JavaScript (and HTML)

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: Seems like a simple imagemap with each pixel defined would do the trick. It is old school html with some javascript added to display the output in either the status bar (really old school) or in a div (fresh flavour).

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
   <div id="status">

    </div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $(document).mousemove(function(e){
          $('#status').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
       }); 
    })
```

**[Pure Javascript solution](http://www.codelifter.com/main/javascript/capturemouseposition1.html)**

> you have to care about browser compatibility while using pure
>   javascript solution

Answer (score 1):

You can get mouse position with jQuery quite easy:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").mousemove(function (e) {
        var pX = e.pageX;
        var pY = e.pageY;
        $("#pixels").html("X="+pX+"; Y="+pY);
    });
});
<div id="pixels"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The html

`<div id="position"></div>`

The js (You just need to include jquery library)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#position").hide();

    $("img").mousemove(function (e) {
        var pX = e.pageX;
        var pY = e.pageY;
        $("#pixels").html("X: "+pX+"; Y: "+pY);
        $("img").hover( function(){$("#pixels").show();} , function(){$("#pixels").hide();}  )
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

[Get Mouse Cursor position - jQuery](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2010/09/jquery-tip-how-to-get-mouse-cursor.html)